Proximity sensor issue on receiving telephone call
This is related to an issue with Android custom ROMs on the legacy device the LG G4, since the move to A12 and A13. This doesn't occur on any version below A12.
I need your help with debugging the black screen issue on telephone calls in A13 on the LG G4.
As soon as we accept a telephone call, the screen goes black, and the only way to interact with the phone is via the power button.
There is some issue with the proximity sensor on this device since A12+.
However, any testing app I have used states that the proximity sensor is detected and works correctly but no ROM seems to make use of it.
We have been doing a lot of testing to help try and find a root cause.
We noticed that if the headset is plugged in, the black screen issue doesn't occur. This behaviour is explained in ProximitySensor.java:

Proximity wake lock will be released if any of the following conditions are true: the audio  is routed through bluetooth, a wired headset, or the speaker; the user requested, received a request for, or is in a video call; or the phone is horizontal while in a call.

We took some logs of phone calls, and I noticed, when filtering on proximity in the logs, we have two different situations:

telephone call with headphones (log filtered by proximity)
=> screenOnImmediately: true

telephone call No headphones (log filtered by proximity and PID of dialer)
=> screenOnImmediately: false


I think we need to debug the code to find out why the proximity sensor doesn't reply correctly, or isn't queried correctly.
I think the important parameter is PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK. See ProximitySensor.java, line 69
and ProximitySensor.java, line 198.
I see references to the parameter PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK in frameworks_base and frameworks_native.

Normally you debug problems by modifying the code, e.g. disabling certain sections or add additional logging vode for getting the state of certain values. If you can not or don't want to decompile a custom version using a trace tool like frida-trace and frida may be an option. It requires a rooted device and allows to hook method calls if arbitrary apps and modify the function arguments and return values at runtime. In the end it is a bit like Xposed just way easier and faster to use which makes it perfect for testing and modifying app behavior.

Hi Robert. I actually do build custom ROMs, so no issue to add debug flags to the source code and recompile. I was hoping someone could guide me on where I should put the debug flags to find out why the variable "screenOnImmediately" is set to false when there is no headset (earphones or BT) attached.

Bump. Anyone can guide me as to where I can set the debug flags ?
